# How to recognize the lightning on the picture?

Tags: opencv

My task is recognition a lightning on the picture. I have chosen to use OpenCV.

I'm using binary tresholding to get image like this.

Original:

[image]

After binary thresholding:

[image]

How now to determine whether there is lightning in the image?

So, how to distinguish lightning on the image from other lines? For example

on this image after binary tresholding i have got the following:
[image]

but if i just count the number of white pixels - i get a wrong answer.

Main part of my code:

```
if ((Igray = cvLoadImage(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)) == 0) {
    return -1;
}
int block_size = atoi(argv[2]);
double offset = (double)atof(argv[3]);

Iat = cvCreateImage(cvSize(Igray -> width, Igray -> height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
// treshold
cvThreshold(Igray, Iat, offset, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
```

Comment: it seems like you got it. binary image mostly shows the lightning . what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I mean - how to determine it using a computer vision? How to find this thin  lines in the image?

Comment: Please post also the code you have (also specify a programming language in the tags). That could help us to help you :D

Comment: sorry, i couldn't figure out. can you draw the desired output on the original image by hand?

Comment: It seems you practically already got your result... Why your binary image is not ok for you?

Comment: you can use cv2.countNonZero(thresholdedImage) in python and get the number of white pixels and if it is greater than some value you can say there is lightning in the image .

Comment: Please don’t ask us to do your work...

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee yees, it's just right! Thanks